# How to go through a list of API keys and repeat for each different request in url list?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from time import perf_counter
import csv

path = "*******************"
domains = []
total_count=0

with open(path, 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in csvreader:
        try:
            website = row[4].split("//")[-1].split("www.")[-1].split('/')[0]
            if website == "":
                continue
            domains.append(website)
        except:
            continue
sample = domains[0:50]

async def fetch(s, body):
    async with s.post('https://****************', json=body) as r:
        if r.status!= 200:
            pass
        enrich_response = await r.json()
        #print(enrich_response)
        employees = enrich_response['employees']
        for employee in employees:
            if(employee['job_title'] == "Owner"):
                print(employee)
                print("************************************************")
                global total_count
                total_count += 1
                print("Total Count:", total_count)
                continue
            elif(employee['job_title'] == "CEO"):
                print(employee)
                print("***************************************************")
                total_count+=1
                print("Total Count:", total_count)
                continue
            else:
               continue

async def fetch_all(s,bodies):
    tasks = []
    for body in bodies:
        task = asyncio.create_task(fetch(s, body))
        tasks.append(task)
    res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return res

async def main():
    # apikeys = list(apikeysone.keys.values())
    bodies = []
    for domain in sample:
        body = {
        "api_key": "********************************",
        "domain" : "{}".format(domain)
        }
        bodies.append(body)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        data = await fetch_all(session, bodies)
        print(data[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = perf_counter()
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    stop = perf_counter()
    print("Time taken:", stop - start)
```

Hi fellow coder!

I have a little problem I'm trying to solve. Can you help?

Let's say I have a list with  API keys. I would like to call on the domains list. For each call I would like to give it to a different API key. That way I would be simultaneously calling on 3 different API keys.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you've already tried? Also, have you tried using a for-loop?

Comment: Will you have one API key for domain? Are you going to make all requests in parallel? Are the API keys less than the number of domains? If so, can you reuse API keys at the same time or do you need to wait for the used ones to complete the connection?

Comment: @MichaelM.  I want to make all calls in parallel, that's why a few api keys. Would for loop work for asyncio to make parallel requests?

Comment: @Pentracchiano No. Yes. Yes. I need to wait for the used ones to complete the request. Basically I've 3 API keys, that call to the same method. One api key can only call one time at the same time, so I can't use the same api key to call in parallel. Let's say there are 20,000 domains and 3 api keys. I need them to go like this: apikey1 domain[0], apikey2 domain[1], apikey3 domain[3] (parallel), once apikey1 finishes calling, go to the next domain and so on. So in essence the number of api keys is how many parallel requests I can make to the same method. And I want to know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would create all the tasks in parallel and make them wait on a `asyncio.Queue` containing the API keys.

Every task would try to get an API key: if one is available, they would remove it from the queue making it inaccessible to the others. Once done, the task will make it available again.

It works for any number of keys.

I am posting only the relevant code:

```py
api_keys = asyncio.Queue()
api_keys.put_nowait("first")
api_keys.put_nowait("second")
api_keys.put_nowait("third")

async def fetch(s, api_keys, body):
    api_key = await api_keys.get()
    # don't put the api_key in the body in the creation of the 
    # task, make the task take one of the available keys and use it
    body = body | {"api_key": api_key}  
    
    # ... your code
    
    # make the key usable again
    api_keys.put_nowait(api_key)
```